# How can I append text to a table cell, overlay it over multiple cells?

Tags: jquery, html-table, custom-data-attribute

I want to find cells in my table with a specific data attribute and overlay text over that cells. My problem is that my table is not correctly displayed anymore.

```js
var name = $('[data-id="12"]').attr("data-name");
var length = $('[data-id="12"]').length;
$('[data-id="12"]').first().append(name);
$('[data-id="12"]').first().attr('colspan', length);
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

td {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <table style="width:600px">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink;border-right-color:pink"></td>
      <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink;border-right-color:pink"></td>
      <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

What I want my table actually look like is this:

[image]

Comment: it's much easier to understand when you use a JsFiddle (or any alternative tool): https://jsfiddle.net/uw90bmza/

Comment: @benams Why? I used the stackoverflow code snippet, that is like jsfiddle

Comment: no...it's not, jsFiddle is a wysiwyg editor, you can change the code there and see how it effects

Comment: Yes, true. But here you could click on "edit" question and then on "edit the above snippet" and do the same thing. Maybe not so comfortable like jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the last two `td` with `[data-id="12"]` that do not have the `colspan` attribute:

```js
var name = $('[data-id="12"]').attr("data-name");
var length = $('[data-id="12"]').length;
$('[data-id="12"]').first().append(name);
$('[data-id="12"]').first().attr('colspan',length);
$('[data-id="12"]').not(":first" ).remove();
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: scroll; /* Scrollbar are always visible */
overflow: auto;
}

div.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

td{height:20px; overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:center}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <table style="width:600px">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink;border-right-color:pink"></td>
    <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink;border-right-color:pink"></td>
    <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var name = $('[data-id="12"]').attr("data-name");
var length = $('[data-id="12"]').length;
var td = '<td data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink;border-right-color:pink" colspan="'+length+'">'+name+'</td>';
$('[data-id="12"]').first().before(td);
$('[data-id="12"]').remove();
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: scroll; /* Scrollbar are always visible */
overflow: auto;
}

div.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

td{height:20px; overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:center}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <table style="width:600px">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink;border-right-color:pink"></td>
    <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink;border-right-color:pink"></td>
    <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an each loop (comments in js below):

```js
var $tds = $('[data-id="12"]'); // get tds

$tds.each(function(index, item) { // loop tds
  var $this = $(item);
  if (index === 0) { // set colspan and text in first td
    $this.attr('colspan', $tds.length).append($this.data("name"));
  } else {
    $this.remove(); // remove others
  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: scroll;
  /* Scrollbar are always visible */
  overflow: auto;
}

div.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

td {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <table style="width:600px">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink;border-right-color:pink"></td>
      <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink;border-right-color:pink"></td>
      <td data-id="12" data-name="elephant" style="background-color:pink"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```